# Are flight tickets required when applying for a Chinese single-entry tourist visa?

Tags: china, tourist-visas, visa-expiration

I have read that a Chinese single-entry tourist visa is valid for about 3 months after issued and that one should send copies of flight reservations when applying. I guess one could cancel those tickets after getting the tourist visa and change to other dates within the 3 months range.

Can you get a Chinese tourist visa without flight tickets and just say "I want to go next week"? Shouldn't a bank statement be enough?

Comment: The length of validity of the visa is country-specific. For instance US citizens can get multiple entry visas valid up to 10 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chinese visa validity is different for every country, currently for the US you can get up to a 10 year visa depending on circumstances.

As for tickets, **yes** if you are applying for a tourist visa your first trip must be scheduled as the application form will require you to fill in the travel dates.

If you are applying for a business visa the rules are slightly different and there are ways to get business visa without a specific first travel date.